# Exporting xmltype columns to file with diacritical marks in it

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I'm buidling a export in PL/SQL to export data about customers. The xml is build up in a temporary table and until that point everything seems to work file.

However, when the xmltype columns are written into files, I run into trouble.

When I for instance have a name like 'Böhomer', and I export it to a file, i see a few things happening:

When I open it with Textpad, everything seems fine, and I see the ö letter

When I open it with a XML editor like Oxygen, I see Bhomer

When I read it with Java, I see B�hmer

I Assume the file should be properly readable by all three of these methods and suspect I do something wrong with the encoding of the files (Although the right data is in the file, since I can see it with textpad, I think I will get complaining customers when I send this kind of XML out)

The problem is, I have no idea how to get it right, or even what the right encoding is. The writing of the files is done by UTL_FILE.

Interesting thing to note is that when I open the file with textpad and save it while explicitly selecting UTF-8 encoding, it becomes readable for the oxygen XML editor and java. I tried to make my PL/SQL code save it as UTF-8, using UTL_FILE.FOPEN_NCHAR procedure, but this only gave me errors like  ORA-29298: Character set mismatch.

Any ideas how I could solve this problem?

My database character set is WE8MSWIN1252

Versions in use:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.2.0  Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

Answer (score 2):

I think I can answer my own question.

I reproduced my problem with the following code:

```
DECLARE
   outputxml   XMLTYPE;

   fileName    VARCHAR2 (100) := 'testfile.xml';
   dir         VARCHAR2 (100) := 'XML_OUTPUT_DIR';
   fHandler    UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
   xmlclob     CLOB;
BEGIN
   --Create some XML
   SELECT   XMLELEMENT ("name", 'Böhmer') INTO outputxml FROM DUAL;

   --Transform it into a clob
   xmlclob := outputxml.getclobval ();

   --Open a file and write the clob and close it
   fHandler := UTL_FILE.FOPEN (dir, fileName, 'W');
   UTL_FILE.PUT (fHandler, xmlclob);
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (fHandler);
END;
```

By changing both the FOPEN and PUT functions (Instead of only the FOPEN function like I did earlier on) to the NCHAR versions, I got a file that was readable by both Oxygen XML editor and Java.

The sample program with the NCHAR functions:

```
DECLARE
   outputxml   XMLTYPE;

   fileName    VARCHAR2 (100) := 'testfile.xml';
   dir         VARCHAR2 (100) := 'XML_OUTPUT_DIR';
   fHandler    UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
   xmlclob     CLOB;
BEGIN
   --Create some XML
   SELECT   XMLELEMENT ("name", 'Böhmer') INTO outputxml FROM DUAL;

   --Transform it into a clob
   xmlclob := outputxml.getclobval ();

   --Open a file and write the clob and close it
   fHandler := UTL_FILE.FOPEN_NCHAR (dir, fileName, 'W');
   UTL_FILE.PUT_NCHAR (fHandler, xmlclob);
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (fHandler);
END;
```